# Return unique hits from a column with multiple values

Tags: python, bash

I have a unique flat file like this. IDs and names are separated by tab, and the following second field has multiple comma separated values:

```
ID1 \t name1,name2,name3
ID2 \t name1,name1,name1,name4
ID3 \t name1,name2,name2,name3
```

I am looking for a way to trim the second field so that every name only comes up once per row. Like so:

```
ID1 \t name1,name2,name3
ID2 \t name1,name4
ID3 \t name1,name2,name3
```

Comment: This seems reasonably straightforward.  What went wrong when you tried it?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I was reading the man for sort and uniq since those are what I used previously but couldn't figure out a way to make it work. @Trelzevir's solution is great, I have no idea why I haven't thought of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have got the second field, use `set()`:

```
set(["name1","name1","name1","name4"])
```

Returns:

```
{'name1', 'name4'}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Honestly, I have no idea why I haven't thought of this.